# Convert columns from a dictionary of dataframes to strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert all columns in all dataframes contained in a dictionary structure, from object to string, in order to apply a cleaning function over strings.

```
# each key represents a dataframe:
# iterate over each dataframe and convert all columns to strings

import pandas as pd


data = {'dataframe_1':pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['John', 'Ashley'], 'col2': ['+10', '-1']}), 'dataframe_2':pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['Italy', 'Brazil', 'Japan'], 'col4': ['Milan', 'Rio do Jaineiro', 'Tokio'], 'percentage':['+95%', '≤0%', '80%+']})}

for key in data:
     data[key].astype(str)
```

However, after applying the above code and given `data['dataframe_1'].info()`, `object` columns remain `object` instead of `string`:

```
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
#Data columns (total 2 columns):
# #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
#---  ------  --------------  ----- 
# 0   col1    2 non-null      object
# 1   col2    2 non-null      object
#dtypes: object(2)
#memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The missing part, was to rename each dataframe inside the loop and change `astype()` argument from `str` to `"string"`:

```
for key in data:
     data[key]=data[key].astype("string")
```

This returns string columns:

```
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
#Data columns (total 2 columns):
# #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
#---  ------  --------------  ----- 
# 0   col1    2 non-null      string
# 1   col2    2 non-null      string
#dtypes: object(2)
#memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
```

Comment: The missing part was also the `data[key]=` .  Pandas transformation functions are not inplace by default, they return new objects.